# Greeks for binary option?

Tags: options, option-pricing, binary

How to derive an analytic formula of greeks for binary option?

We know a vanilla option can be constructed by an asset-or-nothing call and a cash-or-nothing call, does that help us?

Wikipedia states

> Since a binary call is a mathematical derivative of a vanilla call
>   with respect to strike, the price of a binary call has the same shape
>   as the delta of a vanilla call, and the delta of a binary call has the
>   same shape as the gamma of a vanilla call.

Does that mean the delta of a binary call is also the gamma of a vanilla call? Can we use the analytical formula for gamma of vanilla call for binary option?

Comment: Your question reminded me of this MIT OCW lecture partly regarding binaries that I found very insightful: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s096-topics-in-mathematics-with-applications-in-finance-fall-2013/video-lectures/lecture-20-option-price-and-probability-duality/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a digital option with payoff $1_{S_T > K}$, note that, for $\varepsilon > 0$ sufficiently small,
\begin{align}
1_{S_T > K} &\approx \frac{(S_T-(K-\varepsilon))^+ - (S_T-K)^+}{-\varepsilon}.\tag{1}
\end{align}
That is,
The value of the digital option
\begin{align*}
D(S_0, T, K, \sigma) &= -\frac{d C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{d K},
\end{align*}
where $C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)$ is the call option price with payoff $(S_T-K)^+$. Here, we use $d$ rather than $\partial$ to emphasize the full derivative.

If we ignore the skew or smile, that is, the volatility $\sigma$ does not depend on the strike $K$, then
\begin{align*}
D(S_0, T, K, \sigma) &= -\frac{d C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{d K}\\
&= N(d_2)\\
&= N\big(d_1-\sigma \sqrt{T}\big). \tag{2}
\end{align*}
That is, the digital option price has the same shape as the corresponding call option delta $N(d_1)$. Similarly, the digital option delta $\frac{\partial N(d_1-\sigma \sqrt{T})}{\partial S_0}$ has the same shape as the call option gamma $\frac{\partial N(d_1)}{\partial S_0}$. Here, we note that they have the same shape, but **they are not the same**.

However, if we take the volatility skew into consideration, the above conclusion does not hold. Specifically, 
\begin{align*}
D(S_0, T, K, \sigma) &= -\frac{d C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{d K}\\
&= -\frac{\partial C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{\partial K} - \frac{\partial C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{\partial \sigma} \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial K}\\
&= N(d_2) - \frac{\partial C(S_0, T, K, \sigma)}{\partial \sigma} \frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial K},\tag{3}
\end{align*}
which may not have the same shape as $N(d_2)=N(d_1-\sigma \sqrt{T})$. In this case, we prefer to value the digital option using the call-spread approximation given by (1) above instead of the analytical formula (2) or (3).

Answer (score 1):

**Detla (European binary call) = Gamma (European vanilla Call)**, Indeed.

For the derivation, have a look at:

1- [Greeks Binary Call](http://www.wilmottwiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binary_call_option)

2 -[European Option Greek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greeks_(finance))

****Ps: Thus, the answer speaks from itself (*cateris paribus*)****

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the relationship between vanilla and digital options in a model free setting: Let $C$ be the vanilla call, $D$ be the digital call, $E[]$ the expectation under the $T$-forward measure, and assume that the maturity $T$ discount factor is 1 to keep things simple. Then

\begin{eqnarray*}
C&=& E[(S_T - K)^+] \\
D &=& E[1_{S_T > K}] \\
\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0} &=&  E[\frac{\partial S_T}{\partial S_0} 1_{S_T > K}] \\
\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_0^2} &=&  E[\frac{\partial^2 S_T}{\partial S_0^2} 1_{S_T > K}] 
+  E[(\frac{\partial S_T}{\partial S_0})^2 \delta_{S_T = K}] \\
\frac{\partial D}{\partial S_0} &=&  E[\frac{\partial S_T}{\partial S_0} \delta_{S_T = K}] \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Further, under the $T$-forward measure you have $S_T = S_0 M_T$ where $M_t$ is a martingale with value 1 at origin.

Now if you assume that $M_T$ does not depend on $S_0$, such as in the Black & Scholes model, or any homogeneous model, you get

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0} &=&  E[M_T 1_{S_T > K}] \\
\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_0^2} &=&  E[M_T^2 \delta_{S_T = K}] \\
\frac{\partial D}{\partial S_0} &=&  E[M_T \delta_{S_T = K}] \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Since $M_T$ can be used as a Radon-Nikodym derivative, you see that $D$ and $\frac{\partial C}{\partial S_0}$ are expectations of the same quantity under different measures, hence they have the same shape but are not equal, and likewise for $\frac{\partial D}{\partial S_0}$ and $\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial S_0^2}$.