# What is the shape of the delta graph of the binary option?

Tags: greeks, delta, binary-options

I was wondering what the shape of the graph of the delta or the binary option would be.

Comment: This question is also relevant https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/22096/greeks-for-binary-option

Comment: The mnemonic I like is "the price of the binary option looks like the delta of a vanilla option, the delta of a binary option looks like the gamma of a vanilla option". It makes it easy to remeber what he graphs look like.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go for three different levels of volatilities:

[image]